# reactjs: how to use TransitionGroup&CSSTransition with a redirect on login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-transition-group, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm using Laravel & Reactjs with the react-router-dom. I have made a Reactjs login page that redirects the user to the dashboard home page but it doesn't use the csstransition animation. In the dashboard I have an navbar that works with the csstransition. So how can I make the login also with an transition.

login page redirect is true when positive login (inside the render function):

```
   const { redirect } = this.state;
     if (redirect) {
            return <Redirect to='/home'/>;
    }
```

animated switch:

```
//router
const AnimatedSwitch = withRouter(({ location, ...props }) => {

    return (   
    <TransitionGroup>
        <CSSTransition key={location.key} classNames="slide" timeout={350}>
            <Switch location={location}>
                <Route exact path="/home" component={Dashboard} />
                <Route exact path="/clients" render={() => <Clients />} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={() => <Login isAuth={props.isAuth} />} />
            </Switch>
        </CSSTransition>
    </TransitionGroup>
    )
});
```

app render:

```
    render() {
        if (this.state.auth) {
            return (
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Sidebar />
                        <div className="main-panel">
                            <div className="content">
                                <AnimatedSwitch isAuth={this.isAuth}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <div className="main-panel">
                            <AnimatedSwitch isAuth={this.isAuth}/>
                        </div>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Why does the Redirect not use the transition?